# Understanding the output log's auto layout data

Tags: ios8, crash, ios-autolayout

I'm debugging a crash that I believe is auto layout related.  When the crash occurs, I get an enormous dump of information on the output area that begins like this:

> 2015-06-04 13:23:44.158 SpeedySend[22084:861374] Objective: {objective
>   0x7f99e06b3730: <500:242.5, 250:18443.5> +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e061e570.negError{id: 4899} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e061e570.posErrorMarker{id: 4898} + <500:1,
>   250:-1>*0x7f99e061f940.negError{id: 4913} + <500:1,
>   250:1>*0x7f99e061f940.posErrorMarker{id: 4912} + <500:1,
>   250:-1>*0x7f99e061fb40.negError{id: 4915} + <500:1,
>   250:1>*0x7f99e061fb40.posErrorMarker{id: 4914} + <500:1,
>   250:-2>*0x7f99e0620890.negError{id: 4807} + <500:1,
>   250:2>*0x7f99e0620890.posErrorMarker{id: 4806} +
>   <500:2>*0x7f99e06496f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4916} +
>   <500:2>*0x7f99e0649f40.posErrorMarker{id: 4920} + <50 ...

and then runs on for a very long time and ends like this:

> ... 250:-1>*0x7f99e1d77ec0.negError{id: 5023} + <800:1,
>   250:1>*0x7f99e1d77ec0.posErrorMarker{id: 5022} + <500:1,
>   250:-1>*0x7f99e1d78150.negError{id: 5025} + <500:1,
>   250:1>*0x7f99e1d78150.posErrorMarker{id: 5024} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d78310.negError{id: 5027} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d78310.posErrorMarker{id: 5026} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d78620.negError{id: 5045} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d78620.posErrorMarker{id: 5044} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d788c0.negError{id: 5031} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d788c0.posErrorMarker{id: 5030} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d78d30.negError{id: 5033} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d78d30.posErrorMarker{id: 5032} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d790a0.negError{id: 5035} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d790a0.posErrorMarker{id: 5034} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d79460.negError{id: 5037} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d79460.posErrorMarker{id: 5036} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d79840.negError{id: 5039} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d79840.posErrorMarker{id: 5038} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d79c50.negError{id: 5041} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d79c50.posErrorMarker{id: 5040} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d7a080.negError{id: 5043} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d7a080.posErrorMarker{id: 5042} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d7aa60.negError{id: 5047} +
>   <500:1>*0x7f99e1d7aa60.posErrorMarker{id: 5046} +
>   <500:**-7.45058e-08**>*0x7f99e1f7ae60.negError{id: 3600}}

I would like to understand this data better as an aid to debugging my problem.

Is there a document or a posting that I can access that explains the format and meaning of this data?

Like, for instance, what does something like <500:1,250:-1> represent?

What is a negError?

And, most importantly, can something like {id: 3600} be tied back to a specific control that auto layout is laying out for me?

I'm particularly interested in the last questions because I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688370/autolayout-removefromsuperview-removeconstraints-throws-exception-and-crashes) that very small numbers, when seen in these dumps, can indicate a crash due to accumulated loss of floating point precision in the auto layout engine.

You'll note that I have such a number on the very last line of my output data.  So, if I can relate {id: 3600} back to one of my controls, I hope that will put me close to the origin of the problem.

Comment: Use the Cocoa Layout profiler. Record with the profiler's console visible then you can stop recording once an error occurs. In my case I got: 
`Auto layout internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head 0x7fa7da4bbfa0.negError{id: 4472} during optimization of variable with near-zero coefficient, which should never happen.`
Do a search for _0x7fa7da4bbfa0_ under the Event List. This should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Tom Haz thanks for the input.  I haven't tried the Cocoa Layout Profiler but I've just looked at it and it looks like a powerful tool for this sort of thing.  I solved my bug by more prosaic means but the next time one rears its little head, I'm going to whop it with the profiler (smile).  Cheers and thanks!

Comment: Cocoa Layout profiler works only on simulator, and I was facing a problem in ios 7 (simulator not available), so had to work my way out by manually manipulating the constraints. In my case, the problem was with constraints to align centerY position of two views.