# Failed to rebuild layout engine without detectable loss of precision

Tags: objective-c, pure-layout

I'm honestly not sure what's going on here, though I am getting this error multiple times in my Objective-C iOS app. I use [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout) to layout most of my constraints.

`2016-11-29 11:14:41.268847 App Name[4775:1882075] Failed to rebuild layout engine without detectable loss of precision.  This should never happen.  Performance and correctness may suffer.`

I get this line 6 times on seemingly random builds of my app. Sometimes when I build, it happens, sometimes it doesn't. Not sure what triggers it.

Clearly it should "never happen" because I can't find anything on Google, Stackoverflow, or PureLayout about it. Unfortunately it happened to me, even though I'm not sure if it's having any actual impacts.

Comment: Same issue here!

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm getting the same thing here

Comment: Still happens once in a blue moon over here, not sure still if it causes any effects or how to reproduce. Will update here if I get any news.

Comment: I fixed the issue by tweaking some constraints, but I don't remember exactly what I did. What I have found though (which might be related), is this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688370/autolayout-removefromsuperview-removeconstraints-throws-exception-and-crashes

Definitely worth knowing about!

Comment: Had the same thing. In my case it was also constraints. Specifically I had proportional width/height constraint in the (custom) subviews of a stack view. Interface Builder did not know about these constrains as it was a custom subview, hence no compiler warning.