# AutoLayout views make app crash on popViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, swift

**Final Update - Fixed**

I have fixed this. It seems that while playing around (this is my first project in Swift and using AutoLayout) I have changed the `contentCompressionResistancePriority` and `contentHuggingPriority` for some of my views. Taking that code out and reseting all my views to default values in IB fixed my problem.

**Initial Post**

So I am using AutoLayout on iOS to position my dynamic views. It's all working nice and easy 
until I pop one of my view controllers. The app crashes with a really not helpful error message that goes something like this:

```
...
internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head UIImageView:0xd049d50.Width{id: 730}, which should never happen.'
...
```

I've been pocking around and searched the web but I cannot fix it. I've discovered though that there is one line in my code that can make a difference. In my said view controller I have a bunch of `UIImageView`s that are using AutoLayout and who's images I load from the web.

If instead of setting my received image to them I set an empty one (`[[UIImage alloc] init]` or `UIImage()`) in **Swift** as is my case exactly) it doesn't crash anymore.

I even tried setting a dummy image from the app bundle but that makes it crash too.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

**Update 1**

Looking trough the code once more I also found out that there is a constraint related to those `UIImageViews` that also makes the crash to go away when eliminated. It's an aspect ratio constraint and it looks like this

```
imageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 8.0 / 5.0, constant: 0.0))
```

Am I doing something wrong? I really need this aspect ratio to be satisfied so I can't really remove it

**Update 2**

Messing a little bit more with it I've figured a way to make it work. But I'm not happy with it 'cause it didn't made me understand what's going on and it's kind of a hack

Let me layout my view structure to you:

- View

  - Scroll View

    - ContentView

      - Cover ImageView (from IB)
      - Title Label (from IB)
      - ... more Labels or ImageViews in random order from code ...

The way these views are placed is like this:

- The `Cover ImageView` is as wide as the `ContentView` and has an aspect ratio of 8:5 with no space on top
- Each `Label` has a 10px leading space and a 10px trailing space
- Each `ImageView` is as wide as the `ContentView` and has an aspect ratio of 8:5
- All views have a 10px gap beewtwen them and the last one has 10px bottom spacing to the `ContentView`

My fix to my crash was to remove `ContentView` from the stack on `viewWillDisappear` but that makes the screen flash when the ViewController is popped.

I've checked my constraints creating code a 1000 times and it seems right. If you want to see it let me know and I'll post it over here

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688370/autolayout-removefromsuperview-removeconstraints-throws-exception-and-crashes

Comment: Hm... I did read it before and nothing seemed to help. It did make me go trough my code once again and found out another thing. I'll update my question with it

Comment: Seems like your UIImageView.image is being released behind the scenes.

Comment: Another way is dragging the constraint to your VC like you do with the IBOutlet / Action - this way you can change the aspect as you need via code. From the error you maybe trying to set the width with one constraint, and then setting aspect ratio with another ? As a result the 2 constraints clash ?

Comment: It really seems to be a constraint problem somewhere but I can't really figure out what's going on. I can't make my constraints in IB since these views are created programatically based on data I get from a server. I've managed to only make it crash sometimes. I'm still working on it and if I fix it I'll post my solution

Answer (score 11):

Just putting this here in case anyone has the same issue with a dynamic, code-generated `aspectRatio` constraint. I switched the order of the **Height** and **Width** relationship in the aspect-ratio constraint (compare to the one in the question):

```
aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardMedia, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height , relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cardMedia, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)
```

Where the multiplier `aspect` is calculated by:

```
let aspect = image.size.height / image.size.width
```

And that seems to stop the crash from happening. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Ridiculous but it worked..
Changed the aspect ratio constraint in IB from W:H = 16:9 to H:W = 9:16

Comment: Cool. I did that because the item width is fixed in my case, it's just the height that's changing. I followed this equation `item1.attribute1 = multiplier × item2.attribute2 + constant`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the original poster's problem is solved, but I just ran across a similar problem with a different solution. Posting it here in case anyone else runs into my issue and finds this post.

My app was crashing in iOS 7 on the iPhone 5s (in the simulator), but not on iOS 8 or on other devices. I was getting this same error ("Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head ...") when my controllers were being popped... and also when controllers were being scrolled away from in a UIPageViewController.

In both cases, the problem was triggered by the fact that I had full-screen views stacked on top of each other using APIs like UIView.insertSubview:belowSubview: and UIView.bringSubviewToFront: . The solution/workaround was to change our code to dynamically add/remove our views instead of stacking them and shuffling their order.

Hope this helps anyone else who hits the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I've fixed it. It seems that I had somme of my constraints setup incorrectly. After taking a coffee break I figured out which ones and now the thing won't crash anymore.

Comment: You got me headed in the right direction. I removed some aspect ratio constraints that were on a view being dismissed and this problem went away. I'm not sure why that would cause a crash, and it didn't happen 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was because I was trying to layout (with autolayout) the subviews of a view that had a `height == CGFLOAT_MAX.`
Same code works well on iOS7 but crashes on iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar crash myself. Interestingly, it was also with a `UIImageView`. In my case, the problem was alleviated by changing the order of execution of (or removing) the code that adjusted the **content compression resistance** & **content hugging** priorities for this image view.

See more details in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284071/796419

Based on your situation, it seems that your 'aspect ratio' constraint was triggering a similar issue.