# Application crashed when push viewcontroller with animate YES

Tags: ios, autolayout, aspect-ratio

I came across a weird problem when using autolayout. In my xibs, I add some Aspect Ratio constraints. When I push a view controller with animate YES, it crashes with "NSInternalInconsistencyException" and "Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head UIView:" something like that. When the animated is set to NO,it seems ok. And this happens in lower ios8.

Then I found something in [AutoLayout views make app crash on popViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215271/autolayout-views-make-app-crash-on-popviewcontroller). I followed *narsil*'s answer,and somehow fix it. But I couldn't figure it out the reason. It seems I had to remove every Aspect ratio constraint in the viewWillDisappear method whenever it leaves the controller.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Here is the log,I just cut out part of it.

```
[4150:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<NSISEngine: 0x7f8749c3f650>{ Rows:
    0x7f8749c5f500.posErrorMarker{id: 259} == 135 + 1*0x7f8749f80610.marker{id: 80} + 3*0x7f8749f80f00.marker{id: 178} + 1*0x7f8749f80f50.marker{id: 179} + -1*0x7f8749f81310.marker{id: 198} + 1*0x7f8749f81360.marker{id: 199} + 2*0x7f8749f81400.marker{id: 203} + 1*0x7f8749f81770.marker{id: 221} + 1*0x7f8749f81810.marker{id: 224} + -1*0x7f8749f82b30.marker{id: 235} + -1*0x7f8749f82bd0.marker{id: 239} + 1*0x7f8749f82cc0.marker{id: 245} + 1*0x7f8749f82d10.marker{id: 247} + 1*0x7f8749c5f500.negError{id: 260} + 3*0x7f8749f6dc30.posErrorMarker{id: 343} + -3*0x7f8749f6dc30.negError{id: 344}
    0x7f8749c63650.negError{id: 288} == 0 + -1*0x7f8749f80f00.marker{id: 178} + -1*0x7f8749f81400.marker{id: 203} + 1*0x7f8749c63650.posErrorMarker{id: 287} + -1*0x7f8749f6dc30.posErrorMarker{id: 343} + 1*0x7f8749f6dc30.negError{id: 344}
    0x7f8749c63e50.posErrorMarker{id: 289} == 284 + -9.48148*0x7f8749f80570.marker{id: 79} + -0.333333*0x7f8749f80fa0.marker{id: 181} + -0.333333*0x7f8749f81090.marker{id: 186} + -0.666667*0x7f8749f810e0.marker{id: 188} + 0.333333*0x7f8749f81130.marker{id: 189} + -0.333333*0x7f8749f811d0.marker{id: 191} + -0.333333*0x7f8749f81220.marker{id: 194} + 1*0x7f8749f812c0.marker{id: 197} + 0.666667*0x7f8749f82c70.marker{id: 244} + 4.74074*0x7f8749c5f580.posErrorMarker{id: 261} + -4.74074*0x7f8749c5f580.negError{id: 262} + 1*0x7f8749c63e50.negError{id: 290}

Statistics:
    171 rows. Variable counts:
          1 ->  40
          2 ->  50
          3 ->   7
          4 ->  11
          5 ->   6
          6 ->   5
          7 ->   5
          8 ->   2
          9 ->   4
         10 ->   6
         11 ->   6
         12 ->   4
         13 ->   6
         14 ->   5
         15 ->   3
         16 ->   4
         17 ->   4
         19 ->   3
}: internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head UILabel:0x7f874c05b950.Width{id: 5939}, which should never happen.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106cda495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010674a99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106cda2ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000106338054 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 178
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000106337f22 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 147
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001064802e3 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 192
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107364889 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 321
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107362f42 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 206
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000107362b9e -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 218
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107425069 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 320
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010741dfdd __49-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]_block_invoke + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107973c2a -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 78
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107306da4 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke103 + 605
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001073696e8 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 299
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010735568e -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 235
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000107355941 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 78
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a920134 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 310
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010868172d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001086713fc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 354
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d38289 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c85854 __CFRunLoopRun + 1764
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c84d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010900df04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000107310e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    24  Mytest                          0x00000001060b10a3 main + 115
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001089065fd start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```