# Debugging a strange crash - NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm having a strange crash with my application (only with iPad's 9.x) and I'm unsure how I can debug it, because the logs are not helping to discover what is happening.

The strangest thing is that the log shows `Auto layout internal error`, but my application does not have Auto Layout turned on.

Anyone have any idea how to debug whats causing it?

---

[image]

---

Part of the code that I think is responsible for the crash:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapBackground:)];
    [self.ivBackground addGestureRecognizer:tap]; // UIImageView (background)
}

- (void)tapBackground:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409481/auto-layout-internal-error-happening-when-a-view-is-dismissed

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin yeah, but the difference in my case is that `Auto Layout` is turned off on the storyboard.

Comment: there is not too much info on what you're actually doing. Also, you're getting this log in Fabric/Crashlytics as I can see, have you tried stepping through in a debug while running via xcode?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin It's a very rare crash, so I'm not able to simulate the error. This only happens with our customers ;(

Comment: I see...I would say if you have google analytics in your project, I'm assuming you can gather the steps every user is doing in the app. You can also add custom dimension to GA to be user id. You can also add user id key-value to Fabric. Next time you have this crash, you get the id from Fabric. Go to GA and find that session, you'll be able to see step by step what did the user do, and try to repro or analyze it. Also, apple beta testing program allows you to run apple store build schemas through xcode, which might be helpful.

Comment: Admittedly its a guess, as there is little to go on here.  But you should not need to 'endEditing', and also 'dismissViewController'.  The two might conflict - attempt to end editing while view controller is dismissing.  Just do the dismissViewController action, that might cure it.

Comment: Maybe not helpful, but looks like an Apple bug, file a radar on http://radar.apple.com, they may also provide some solution for you. Or you'll just have to wait for an iOS update.

Comment: @Alistra thank you, I reported it.

Comment: Just a minor note. You cannot turn off `Auto Layout` any more. Autoresizing is internally converted into auto layout constraints anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the crash log you can see that it has to do with the device's keyboard. Could you please expand the crash log between lines 4 and 36 or upload the full crash log so I can take a look. Thanks

It's also flagged as a `bug!` inside the crash log.

**Update:**

After checking the full log, it looks like a single finger tap

```
20 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:]
```

is causing the textField to become first responder, which is setting up the keyboard, but at the same time the gesture has triggered the endEditing and the dismissal of the viewController.

The keyboard is crashing the app as the textField has been removed before the Autolayout has finished setting up.

I would relook at how you structure your views and the gesture, and how you dismiss or close that VC.

Comment: One scenario that could cause this is pressing on the imageview, triggering the gesture, and pressing on the text view at the same time, triggering the firstResponder call. Possibly duration device rotation ??

Comment: I'll share the full VC code. Device rotation is disabled, only portrait is supported.