# iOS : App crashes with uncaught exception of type NSException (Auto-layout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, nsexception

I'm working on an app which is almost complete. On one of the view controller (Detail view controller whose views are hide/show based on web service response) a random crash occur and I am unable to find the reason for this crash. 
You can find console messages here:

```
Objective: {objective 0x7a9c0590: <1000:37, 750:66.9, 251:1878.7, 250:887.8, 249:469> + <750:-1>*0x79653e10.marker{id: 12643} + <249:1>*0x79709560.marker{id: 11792} + <249:-1>*0x79709c10.marker{id: 11785} + <249:-1>*0x7ae2fbd0.marker{id: 11787} + <249:-1>*0x7ae32260.marker{id: 11790} + <249:-1>*0x7ae326f0.marker{id: 11795} + <249:-1>*0x7ae327e0.marker{id: 11810} + <750:-1, 249:-1>*0x7ae35d00.marker{id: 11829} + <250:1>*0x7ae38070.marker{id: 12335} + <250:1>*0x7ae3a4b0.marker{id: 12261} + <999:2>*0x7ae41dc0.negError{id: 11780} + <999:2>*0x7ae41f70.negError{id: 11783} + <249:-1>*0x7ae42f80.marker{id: 11818} + <1000:0.7, 750:2.33, 251:-1.66, 250:-5.39>*0x7ae42fb0.marker{id: 11820} + <1000:0.7, 750:2.33, 251:-1.66, 250:-5.39>*0x7ae42fe0.marker{id: 11822} + <249:-1>*0x7ae43100.marker{id: 11835} + <250:-1>*0x7ae43130.marker{id: 11837} + <249:-1>*0x7ae43160.marker{id: 11839} + <250:-1>*0x7ae43190.marker{id: 11841} + <1000:0.7, 750:2.33, 251:-1.66, 250:-4.39>*0x7ae431c0.marker{id: 11843} + <1000:0.7, 750:2.33, 251:-1.66, 250:-4.39>*0x7ae43310.marker{id: 11850} + <1000:0.7, 750:2.33, 251:-1.66, 250:-4.39>*0x7ae43770.marker{id: 11869} + <250:1>*0x7ae43890.marker{id: 12372} + <250:1>*0x7ae438c0.marker{id: 12374} + <250:1>*0x7ae439b0.marker{id: 12430} + <250:1>*0x7ae439e0.marker{id: 12433} + <250:1>*0x7ae43a10.marker{id: 12436} + <250:1>*0x7ae43a40.marker{id: 12438} + <250:1>*0x7ae43a70.marker{id: 12441} + <250:1>*0x7ae43aa0.marker{id: 12444} + <750:1>*0x7ae43bf0.marker{id: 11894} + <750:1>*0x7ae43c20.marker{id: 11896} + <750:0.33, 251:-0.66, 250:-0.99>*0x7ae43dd0.marker{id: 11920} + <750:0.33, 251:-0.66, 250:-0.99>*0x7ae43e00.marker{id: 11922} + <251:-1, 250:-1>*0x7ae43e60.marker{id: 11926} + <251:-1, 250:-1>*0x7ae43e90.marker{id: 11928} + <1000:0.7, 250:-1.4>*0x7ae43f50.marker{id: 11936} + <1000:0.7, 250:-1.4>*0x7ae43fb0.marker{id: 11942} + <250:-1>*0x7ae44010.marker{id: 11945} + <250:-1>*0x7ae44070.marker{id: 11949} + <750:-1, 251:1, 250:2>*0x7ae443c0.marker{id: 11969} + <750:1, 250:-1>*0x7ae44490.marker{id: 11972}
.
.
.
<249:1>*0x7ae6bd70:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height.marker{id: 12568} +
<999:0.00277778>*_UILayoutGuide:0x7ae41d10.Width{id: 11781} + 
<999:0.00277778>*_UILayoutGuide:0x7ae41ec0.Width{id: 11784}}

Constraints:
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ae6bda0 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ae41c70]   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7a950650 )>        Marker:0x7ae6bda0:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left.marker{id: 12571}
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ae6bdd0 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ae41c70]   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7a950650 )>     Marker:0x7ae6bdd0:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top.marker{id: 12572}
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7ae46ae0 V:[UIImageView:0x7ae3fc00(117)] Hug:251 CompressionResistance:750>        Marker:0x7ae46ae0.posErrorMarker{id: 12665}
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7ae49b50 H:[UIImageView:0x7ae3fc00(640)] Hug:251 CompressionResistance:750>        Marker:0x7ae49b50.posErrorMarker{id: 12663}
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7ae5a310 V:[UISearchBar:0x7ae384e0(44)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>     Marker:0x7ae5a310.posErrorMarker{id: 12447}
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7ae63920 H:[UILabel:0x7ae45380'call'(23.5)] Hug:251 CompressionResistance:750>     Marker:0x7ae63920.posErrorMarker{id: 12453}
.
.
.
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7ae489d0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UILabel:0x7ae470f0'Gallery'(30)]>        Marker:0x7ae489d0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 12157}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79653e10 V:[UILabel:0x7ae382c0'Label'(0)]>        Marker:0x79653e10.marker{id: 12643}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79665350 V:[UIView:0x7ae42650(0)]>        Marker:0x79665350.marker{id: 12646}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ae326f0 V:[UIView:0x7ae42990]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ae41ec0]>       Marker:0x7ae326f0.marker{id: 11795}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ae32720 V:[UIView:0x7ae42720]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ae41ec0]>       Marker:0x7ae32720.marker{id: 11798}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ae32750 V:[UIView:0x7ae427f0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ae41ec0]>       Marker:0x7ae32750.marker{id: 11801}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ae32780 UISearchBar:0x7ae384e0.width == UIView:0x7ae41c70.width>     Marker:0x7ae32780.marker{id: 11804}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ae327b0 H:[UISearchBar:0x7ae384e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ae41c70 )>      Marker:0x7ae327b0.marker{id: 11807}
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ae327e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ae41d10]-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x7ae384e0]>      Marker:0x7ae327e0.marker{id: 11810}
.
.
.
Integralization Adjustments:(none)

Statistics:
342 rows. Variable counts:
      1 ->  65
      2 ->  47
      3 ->  16
      4 ->  15
      5 ->  18
      6 ->  24
      7 ->  19
      8 ->  15
      9 ->   5
     10 ->  22
     11 ->  14
     12 ->  10
     13 ->   8
     14 ->   9
     15 ->  13
     16 ->   3
     17 ->   3
     18 ->   1
     20 ->   1
     21 ->   1
     22 ->   1
     23 ->   1
     25 ->   1
     28 ->   1
     29 ->   1
     30 ->   1
     31 ->   1
     34 ->   1
     35 ->   1
     36 ->   1
     37 ->   1
     40 ->   1
     41 ->   1
     42 ->   1
     43 ->   1
     46 ->   1
     47 ->   1
     48 ->   1
     49 ->   1
     51 ->   1
     54 ->   1
     55 ->   1
     56 ->   1
     57 ->   1
     58 ->   1
     59 ->   1
     60 ->   1
     62 ->   1
     63 ->   1
     65 ->   1
     66 ->   3
}: internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head 0x7ae46d90.slackMarker{id: 12081}, which should never happen.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x016e1946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0136aa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x016e186d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
3   Foundation                          0x00f5879c -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 256
4   Foundation                          0x00f581bd -[NSISEngine optimize] + 193
5   Foundation                          0x00f5fe46 -[NSISEngine constraintDidChangeSuchThatMarker:shouldBeReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:] + 339
6   Foundation                          0x00f5fca4 -[NSISEngine tryToChangeConstraintSuchThatMarker:isReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:undoHandler:] + 487
7   Foundation                          0x00f48f95 -[NSLayoutConstraint _tryToChangeContainerGeometryWithUndoHandler:] + 584
8   Foundation                          0x00f48a6b -[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:] + 423
9   Foundation                          0x00f49e82 -[NSLayoutConstraint setConstant:] + 52
10  Byron-App                           0x001c1e34 -[DirectoryDetailViewController loadData] + 2868
11  Byron-App                           0x001c0930 -[DirectoryDetailViewController fetchBusinessDetail] + 624
12  Foundation                          0x00f6ff07 -[NSThread main] + 76
13  Foundation                          0x00f6fe60 __NSThread__main__ + 1326
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03b7eecf _pthread_body + 138
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03b7ee45 _pthread_body + 0
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03b7cf0e thread_start + 34
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

You can find the full error log on the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1noH4KPfAePRHZwTzk3RUo4Zjg/view?usp=sharing

By random crash I mean it does not crashes all the time, going back and re-entering in this view causing this crash.

I'm using iOS 8, Auto-layout (size classes: Compact Width/Any Height).

P.S: In order to show/hide views I've set IBOutlets to height constraints and I'm setting these constraint outlets to zero in order to hide the respective view.

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: A 61 page error log? Narrow it down if you can.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer please see my updated question. a brief error log has been added.

Comment: I'll be honest and say I myself do not have much knowledge of how to deal with this. However, [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688370/autolayout-removefromsuperview-removeconstraints-throws-exception-and-crashes) or [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215271/autolayout-views-make-app-crash-on-popviewcontroller) might help. Head over and check these out.