# Weird crash on present modally a view controller on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, storyboard

I developed an app using a iOS 9 device for testing and everything is fine, but I need the compatibility with **iOS 7** also.

At the start I load a view controller with some buttons, one of them should present modally another controller but on iOS 7 device I get a very weird crash:

> Objective: {objective 0x165f98c0: <> +
>   <750:-6.61817e-08>*0x16569cd0.negError{id: 118} +
>   <999:2>*0x16569ec0.negError{id: 175} + <999:2>*0x16570520.negError{id:
>   172} + <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0.Width{id: 176} +
>   <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70.Width{id: 173}} 2016-04-27
>   15:38:07.483 191PerTe[502:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '{ Rows:    0x16569ec0.posErrorMarker{id: 174} == 0 +
>   1*0x16569ec0.negError{id: 175} + 1*_UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0.Width{id:
>   176}  0x16570520.posErrorMarker{id: 171} == 0 +
>   1*0x16570520.negError{id: 172} + 1*_UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70.Width{id:
>   173}  UITransitionView:0x165a21d0.Height{id: 159} == 960 +
>   1*0x165f11b0.marker{id: 150} + 2*0x1655ed20.marker{id: 168}
>     UITransitionView:0x165a21d0.Width{id: 154} == 640 +
>   1*0x1655f650.marker{id: 164}  UITransitionView:0x165a21d0.minX{id:
>   162} == 0 + 2*0x1658f790.marker{id: 161} + -0.5*0x1655f650.marker{id:
>   164}  UITransitionView:0x165a21d0.minY{id: 163} == 0 +
>   2*0x1655f080.marker{id: 167} + -1*0x1655ed20.marker{id: 168}
>     UIView:0x1659fb60.Height{id: 185} == 960 + 1*0x165f11b0.marker{id:
>   150} + 2*0x1655ed20.marker{id: 168} + 2*0x16559660.marker{id: 194}
>     UIView:0x1659fb60.Width{id: 188} == 640 + 1*0x1655f650.marker{id:
>   164} + 2*0x1656b160.marker{id: 190}   UIView:0x1659fb60.minX{id: 187}
>   == 0 + 2*0x165596b0.marker{id: 186} + -1*0x1656b160.marker{id: 190}   UIView:0x1659fb60.minY{id: 189} == 0 + 2*0x1656b190.marker{id: 193} +
>   -1*0x16559660.marker{id: 194}     UIWindow:0x165a6fe0.Height{id: 141} == 960 + 1*0x165f11b0.marker{id: 150}   UIWindow:0x165a6fe0.Width{id: 136}
>   == 640 + 1*0x165ae3a0.marker{id: 147}     UIWindow:0x165a6fe0.minX{id: 144} == 0 + 2*0x16588c90.marker{id: 143} + -0.5*0x165ae3a0.marker{id:
>   147}  UIWindow:0x165a6fe0.minY{id: 146} == 0 + 2*0x165f4e20.marker{id:
>   145} + -0.5*0x165f11b0.marker{id: 150}
>     _UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0.Height{id: 182} == 0 +
>   1*0x1656c6a0.marker{id: 181}  _UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0.minY{id: 184}
>   == 960 + 1*0x165f11b0.marker{id: 150} + 2*0x1655ed20.marker{id: 168} + -1*0x1656c6a0.marker{id: 181} + 1*0x1656b5f0.marker{id: 183} + 2*0x16559660.marker{id: 194}    _UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70.Height{id:
>   178} == 40 + 1*0x1656af20.marker{id: 177}
>     _UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70.minY{id: 180} == 0 +
>   1*0x165676a0.marker{id: 179}  objective{id: 1} == {objective
>   0x165f98c0: <> + <750:-6.61817e-08>*0x16569cd0.negError{id: 118} +
>   <999:2>*0x16569ec0.negError{id: 175} + <999:2>*0x16570520.negError{id:
>   172} + <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0.Width{id: 176} +
>   <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70.Width{id: 173}}
>
> Constraints:           Marker:0x16559660.marker{id: 194}
>          Marker:0x165596b0.marker{id: 186}
>   (Integralization adjustment:3.20747e-06)
>            Marker:0x1655ed20.marker{id: 168}
>          Marker:0x1655f080.marker{id: 167}
>          Marker:0x1655f650.marker{id:
>   164}          Marker:0x1656b160.marker{id: 190}
>   (Integralization adjustment:6.41495e-06)
>          Marker:0x1656b190.marker{id: 193}
>           Marker:0x1658f790.marker{id: 161}
>          Marker:0x165ae3a0.marker{id: 147}
>          Marker:0x165f11b0.marker{id: 150}
>     <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x165676a0
>   V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1659fb60
>   )>        Marker:0x165676a0.marker{id: 179}
>     <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x16569ec0
>   H:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0(0@999)]
>   priority:999>     Marker:0x16569ec0.posErrorMarker{id: 174}
>     <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1656af20
>   V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70(20)]>        Marker:0x1656af20.marker{id: 177}
>     <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1656b5f0
>   _UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0.bottom == UIView:0x1659fb60.bottom>     Marker:0x1656b5f0.marker{id: 183}
>     <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1656c6a0
>   V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1655a6c0(0)]>     Marker:0x1656c6a0.marker{id: 181}
>     <_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x16570520
>   H:[_UILayoutGuide:0x165a3c70(0@999)]
>   priority:999>     Marker:0x16570520.posErrorMarker{id: 171}
>     <_UIWindowAnchoringConstraint:0x16588c90 h=--- v=---
>   UIWindow:0x165a6fe0.midX == + 160>        Marker:0x16588c90.marker{id: 143}
>     <_UIWindowAnchoringConstraint:0x165f4e20 h=--- v=---
>   UIWindow:0x165a6fe0.midY == + 240>        Marker:0x165f4e20.marker{id: 145}
>
> Integralization Adjustments: 0x165596b0.marker{id: 186}
>   [] ->
>   0.000003 0x1656b160.marker{id: 190} [] ->
>   0.000006
>
> Statistics:     18 rows. Variable counts:
>           1 ->   6
>           2 ->  10
>           3 ->   1
>           5 ->   1 }: internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head 0x16569cd0.negError{id: 118}, which should never
>   happen.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2f3cef83 0x39b7fccf 0x2f3ceec5 0x2fd3a315 0x2fd39e57 0x2fd35b95 0x31beacd3 0x31e832ab 0x31be9bc1
>   0x31d02f4f 0x31c23d57 0x31c23c73 0x31870111 0x3a06781f 0x3a067777
>   0x2f3998a1 0x2f398175 0x2f302ebf 0x2f302ca3 0x34208663 0x31c4f14d
>   0x28f3f 0x3a08cab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

I already tried to:

- disable size classes
- reset all constraints on the other controller, present modally a blank view controller
- obviously everything is working on iOS 8/9

Some advice?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? Looks like your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28975033/1545952

Comment: I've seen it but I haven't any additional views, I'm trying to present a empty view controller and I still get this crash :\