# How To Properly Set Constraints To Multiple Buttons With Same Size To Prevent "Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head"

Tags: ios, autolayout, aspect-ratio

The layout you can see below is a `UIViewController` having four buttons with same size aligned horizontally and a `UIPageViewController` below them. The `UIPageViewController` holds 4 pages. Each page contains a `UITableView`.

[image]

The four buttons is embedded in a UIView in which the constraints I set is:

- leading to super view
- top to TopLayoutGuide.bottom
- trailing to super view
- aspect ratio (height equal to width 5:32)

The constraints of the buttons inside are like:

- every button has constraint to top and bottom space to super view
- first and last has constraint to leading and trailing of super view
- every button's width is equal to the first

The problem is, sometimes when this view controller transitions to another view controller, the app will crash. The error would be "Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head". When I check the memory address of which control produced the crash, it was always the first button which has a title "Live Radio".

The problem would be solved if I set the height of the container view(view that embeds the four buttons) to a fixed value, not aspect ratio. However, I want the size of the tabs to expand with respect to the size of the screen. So, this won't be a good solution for me.

Is there any other way to make the four buttons expand proportionally with the screen without using aspect ratio?

Thanks!

-------- EDIT ---------

Regarding how I transition to another view controller, it's just plain

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifer:@"showArtistDetailsView"];
```

Comment: show us how you transition this view controller to another one.

Comment: @lawicko I edited my question

Comment: what we really need to see is the `showArtistsDetailsView`, the faulty bit may be there.

Comment: @lawicko what part would that be? The constraints and layout of ArtistDetailsView?

Comment: nevermind, I discovered it's probably a bug in autolayout, did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29108357/703809)?

Comment: Thanks man! it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem fixed by interchanging the width and height of the aspect ratio constraint of the "Live Radio" button.