# Invalid update: invalid numbers of items in section 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uicollectionview

I'm using the Core Data delegate methods to update my `UICollectionView`.

I get this error even though everything with the code seems to be OK:

```
2014-03-28 22:27:07.196 Magin[5387:60b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
-controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section
after the update (8) must be equal to the number of items contained in
that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of items
inserted or deleted from that section (8 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus
 or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0
 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

Here is the update code:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{

    NSMutableDictionary *change = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            change[@(type)] = @(sectionIndex);
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            change[@(type)] = @(sectionIndex);
            break;
    }

    [_sectionChanges addObject:change];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    NSMutableDictionary *change = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            change[@(type)] = newIndexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            change[@(type)] = indexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            change[@(type)] = indexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            change[@(type)] = @[indexPath, newIndexPath];
            break;
    }
    [_objectChanges addObject:change];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if ([_sectionChanges count] > 0)
    {
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

            for (NSDictionary *change in _sectionChanges)
            {
                [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

                    NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                            [self.collectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]]];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                            [self.collectionView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]]];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                            [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]]];
                            break;
                    }
                }];
            }
        } completion:nil];
    }

    if ([_objectChanges count] > 0 && [_sectionChanges count] == 0)
    {

        if ([self shouldReloadCollectionViewToPreventKnownIssue] || self.collectionView.window == nil) {
            // This is to prevent a bug in UICollectionView from occurring.
            // The bug presents itself when inserting the first object or deleting the last object in a collection view.
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611292/uicollectionview-assertion-failure
            // This code should be removed once the bug has been fixed, it is tracked in OpenRadar
            // http://openradar.appspot.com/12954582
            [self.collectionView reloadData];

        } else {

            [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

                for (NSDictionary *change in _objectChanges)
                {
                    [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

                        NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
                        switch (type)
                        {
                            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                                [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                                break;
                            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                                [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                                break;
                            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                                [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                                break;
                            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                                [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:obj[0] toIndexPath:obj[1]];
                                break;
                        }
                    }];
                }
            } completion:nil];
        }
    }


    [_sectionChanges removeAllObjects];
    [_objectChanges removeAllObjects];
}

- (BOOL)shouldReloadCollectionViewToPreventKnownIssue {
    __block BOOL shouldReload = NO;
    for (NSDictionary *change in _objectChanges) {
        [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = obj;
            switch (type) {
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                    if ([self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:indexPath.section] == 0) {
                        shouldReload = YES;
                    } else {
                        shouldReload = NO;
                    }
                    break;
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                    if ([self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:indexPath.section] == 1) {
                        shouldReload = YES;
                    } else {
                        shouldReload = NO;
                    }
                    break;
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                    shouldReload = NO;
                    break;
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                    shouldReload = NO;
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }

    return shouldReload;
}
```

_objectChanges and _secitonChanges are objects of type NSMutableArray.

Comment: Does this code work or there's a crash?

Comment: There is no crash but the collection view freezes and doesn't updates the UI. This error is logged in the console.

Comment: Seems like something wrong with your `NSFetchRequest`