# Insert cell and section causing unexpected crash

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I did updated my data source, I dont use headers or footer in my collection view.
At the first delegate its empty, then after the user add some data to the model, I am trying to add a new cell and section with :

```
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: (0) )
 collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

            self.collectionView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index:0 ))
            self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

The crash has no explanation, but says something about array index - I don't know which array .

```
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

on the first row where you insert the section. (data has 1 value in the array!)

I could see some people said its a bug ?

Comment: Does data have 1 value in the array before or after you try to show the collectionview?  The order in which you add the item and show the view is important.

Comment: What does your [cellForItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:) implementation look like?  My psychic powers tell me the problem is there.

Comment: "I could see some people said its a bug ?" I would like to quash that sort of thinking. The chances of your discovering a bug in Cocoa are vanishingly small. Learn to suspect _your_ code.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` call.  By inserting the section you are implicitly inserting all the cells that the datasource says are going to be in that section.

Comment: Well, First, I updated the data model before everything. Regarding @dan I did tried to remove the insert cell, and I get the same error. the rest of my implementation is good, because if I use the reload data function it works great. This is the bug I was talking about : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611292/uicollectionview-assertion-failure

Comment: @vadian as I wrote 3 times, the obvious thing after 5 years is to update before you insert....

Comment: The error message says, an object is going to be inserted at index **1** so logically the batch update block cannot cause the crash.